# Field formatter only displays file name not link to file

Tags: files

I installed Drupal 8.3.5, no extra plugins or themes. I have added in the "base page" (structure/type) a field (file_in) to upload files.

If I add a new page (node/add/page) and also load a file in file_in (file2.txt), the new page displays me the link to the file.

Then I add a new field called file_ext as entity reference (file type). If I add a new page (node/add/page) and put in file_ext a reference to the file2.txt, I see the new page, but with only the label name of the file, not its link.

File module is enabled, version Drupal 8.3.5 (new and clean).

Comment: You can probably control the display format on the content type display tab. Edit your content type, go to the manage display tab and choose a different format for your field.

Comment: Your question is not clear. General rule: the more time you spend to word your question and also format (!) the more likely you will get the right answer. For me, it was hard to read and could understand only after the second time.

Comment: I have:

Label --> "Link to the referenced entity"
Rendered entity --> only "Rendered as Default"
Entity ID

No option displays the link, but only the text (the file name)

You can test

https://r2ghn.ply.st/admin/structure/types/manage/page/display

Comment: With all the dead links this issue can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to (*structure -> content types -> page -> manage display*):

**/admin/structure/types/manage/page/display**

and set your fields format and its corresponding settings the way you prefer.

---

Further reading on the topic: [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/display-modes-view-modes-and-form-modes)

Youtube tutorial: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D_llkTX6II)

Comment: I have:

Label --> "Link to the referenced entity"
Rendered entity --> only "Rendered as Default"
Entity ID

No option displays the link, but only the text (the file name)

You can test

https://r2ghn.ply.st/admin/structure/types/manage/page/display